# Why does Javascript have much fewer blocking functions than Python

Tags: javascript, python, multithreading, async-await, python-asyncio

Moving from Javascript to Python, and looking at `asyncio` has me a little confused.

As someone who is new to the fundamental concepts of concurrency, I just assumed a superficial understanding of Javascript concurrency.

A basic understanding from using `async / await` in Javascript:

If we run any processes inside an `async` function, and `await` the response of the function, we are essentially waiting for the function to set a value on the `Promise`.

Makes total sense - when the `Promise` is given a value, we can also use callbacks such as `.then()` to handle the response. Alternatively, just `await`.

Whatever the underlying implementation of asynchronicity here is (for example all processes running on a single thread with an event loop), should it matter how we interface with it?

Now, I move to Python and start playing with `asyncio`. We have `Futures`, just like `Promises`. All of a sudden, I can't use my standard libraries, such as `request.get(...)`, but I need to use non blocking network requests in libraries such as `aiohttp`.

What does blocking / non-blocking mean here? I assume it means the single thread that the event loop is on is blocked, so we cant process other functions in parallel.

So my 2 questions then are:

- What causes the single thread to be blocked? For example in `requests.get(...)`
- Why are most functions non-blocking in Javascript, but not in Python (i.e we don't need specific libraries such as `aiohttp`).

And what about languages like `Go` with their `goroutines`? Is it just a case because its a new language with concurrency built in from the beginning, that the concept of blocking functions don't exist. Or in Go it's not a single thread, so everything can inherently be parallelised?

Thanks :)

Comment: From my understanding, JavaScript probably has much less blocking functions because it is single-threaded and blocking functions in non-async functions freeze the entire page until they're done

Comment: @VilgotanL they could freeze the entire page also if they were taking too long on their own to execute (for example synchronous large data processing inside the function)

Comment: Remember that `async / await` were only added to Javascript in 2017.  It's not like they were baked in to the language from the start.

Comment: @TimRoberts: That said, an event loop (which is what you need to implement them) *was* baked in from the start; Python didn't have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Event loop

Javascript, and python's async io make use of a concurrency model based on [event loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop).

*(Note the plural because you could have multiple event loops which handle different kinds of tasks e.g. disk io, network io, ipc, parallel computations etc)*

The general concept of an event loop is that, you have a number of things to do, so you put those things in a queue, and once in a while (like every nanosecond), the event loop picks an event from the queue, and runs it for a short while (maybe a millisecond or so), and either shoves it back in the queue if it hasn't completed, or waits until it yields control back to the event loop.

---

Now to answer some of your questions:

> What does blocking / non-blocking mean here? I assume it means the
> single thread that the event loop is on is blocked, so we cant process
> other functions in parallel.

### Blocking event loop

Blocking the event loop occurs when the event loop is running a task, and the task has either not finished or given back control to the event-loop, for a period of time longer than the event loop has scheduled it to run.

In the case of python's requests library, they make use of a synchronous http library, which doesn't respect the event loop; Therefore, running such a task in the loop will starve other tasks which are patiently waiting their turn to run, until the request is finished.

> Why are most functions non-blocking in Javascript, but not in Python
> (i.e we don't need specific libraries such as `aiohttp`).

#### JS

Everything in Javascript can block the event loop. The only way not to block the event loop is to make heavy use of callbacks via [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout). However, if care is not taken, even those callbacks can block the event loop if they run too long without yielding control back to the event loop via another `setTimeout` call.

*(If you've never had to use `setTimeout`, but have used promises and async network requests in JS, then you are probably making use of a library that does. Most of the popular networking libraries used in browsers (ajax, axios, fetch, etc), are based on the popular [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) API, which provides async network IO.)*

#### Python

In python, the story is slightly different: Before asyncio, there was no such thing as as "event loop". Everything must run to completion before python interpreter moves on to the next thing. This is part of what makes python very easy to learn (and dare I say, to create...). The reason for this, comes in the form of the python [GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/), which in simple terms enforces a single order of execution for any python program. I encourage you to click that link, and read why the GIL exists.

> And what about languages like `Go` with their `goroutines`?

*Note*: I am not a go programmer, but I read [something](https://medium.com/@ankur_anand/illustrated-tales-of-go-runtime-scheduler-74809ef6d19b)

#### How is Go different?

The only difference between the way go handles goroutines and how python asyncio/js do their event loops, is that go makes more use of os threads to ensure that threads are scheduled fairly and make full use of the machine they run in.

While js callbacks/asyncio tasks will often run in the same thread as the event loop, goroutines are able to run in seperate OS threads and over multiple cores, thus giving them higher availability and higher parallelism. *(In that case, we could almost consider goroutines to be closer to OS threads in terms of how much time they actually get to run, as compared to green threads which are bound by the amount of time the event loop's thread runs.)*

Comment: Fantastic answer, thanks so much!